# How to get width and height from CreateWindowEx() window? C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, window

I have made a window with CreateWindowEx() function, now how do i get the width and height from that window i created? This sounds very basic thing to do, but i just couldnt find any answer ;_;

This is needed because the window height is created automatically depending on how the Windows wants to create it.

Language C or C++

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519(VS.85).aspx).  Subtract the right from the left to get the width and the bottom from the top to get the height.

```
RECT rect;
if(GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect))
{
  int width = rect.right - rect.left;
  int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
}
```

As a side note, if you'd like the client area instead of the entire window.  You can use [GetClientRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633503(VS.85).aspx).  For other information about the window you can use [GetWindowInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633516(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for [GetWindowInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633516(v=vs.85).aspx)

Example:

```
HWND window = ::CreateWindowEx(...);
WINDOWINFO info;
if ( ::GetWindowInfo(window, &info) ) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`GetWindowRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519(VS.85).aspx) or [`GetWindowInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633516(VS.85).aspx) which returns a [`WINDOWINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632610(VS.85).aspx) structure?

Comment: GetWindowRect() was the right thing to go with, thanks to you all guys!

Answer (score 1):

Given there's no indication why you need the size, and that the size can change if the window style is set to include resizable attributes [and the user resizes the window using minimize/maximize/restore or drags a window edge], your safest choice is to include a message handler for WM_SIZE and use the wparam and lparam parameter values to determine window dimensions.  This way, you'll always know the current size.  WM_SIZE is called in the sequence of messages post window creation.